# Using nth child to target every other TWO divs

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to use nth child to select every other TWO divs.

This means, when there is a collection of divs 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6 - I need to select 1, 2, 5 and 6. Every other two.

CSS:

```
#navigation .menuItem:nth-child(3n+3) {  
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="menuItemWrapper">
            <div class="menuItem"><a href="shop.html">Shop Online</a></div>
            <div class="menuItem"><a href="blog.html">The Blog</a></div>
            <div class="menuItem"><a href="lookbook.html">LookBook</a></div>
            <div class="menuItem"><a href="gift-finder.html">Gift Finder</a></div>
            <div class="menuItem"><a href="about.html">About Us</a></div>
            <div class="menuItem sub"><a href="freebies.html">Tutorials</a></div>
            <div class="menuItem sub"><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></div>
            <div class="menuItem sub"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></div>
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8Uxt/)

Answer (score 11):

You won't be able to do it with a single selector, but you can with two:

```
#navigation .menuItem:nth-child(4n+1), #navigation .menuItem:nth-child(4n+2) {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3VQcP/)

Comment: This is brill. Got a small problem though, I have a hidden div in there which I forgot about (it's not output at this screen resolution). It is however counted in this calculation. So it actually needs to be 1, 2, 5 and 7 as the 6th one is in fact hidden (I didn't include it in my example above)

Comment: That makes life much trickier. Unless you can not give it the `menuItem` class? In which case it'll be invisible to `.menuItem:nth-child` too.

Comment: Unfortunately not as it throws the entire menu out on the other resolutions. I tried adding a class just to these items (rather than removing it), I added `forMobile` class to all menu items except the hidden one, and changed your `nth-child` code to match that classname, but that didn't seem to work...

Comment: Ah, it looks like I misunderstood `nth-child`. It selects the `nth` element, if it matches the type given; not the `nth` element of the type given, so `.forMobile:nth-child(4n+1)` still counts the hidden div, but doesn't select it. If you can make the divider a different element type (so, not a `div`), then `div:nth-of-type(4n+1)` does the job; sadly `.forMobile:nth-of-type(4n+1)` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple hack for this:

Firstly: set global color for your lined-up `<div>`s

```
.menuItemWrapper>div { background-color: #fff; }
```

Secondly: select every 4th element and apply alternative background to `<div>` element directly after it. That makes pairs. -1 to begin from the right place.

```
.menuItemWrapper>div:nth-child(4n-1) { background-color: #ccc; }
.menuItemWrapper>div:nth-child(4n-1)+div { background-color: #ccc; }
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

@Francesca here's a simple and awesome tool for :nth tester by css-trickes, its making the life easier for selectors [css-tricks nth-child-tester](http://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/)

Answer (score 1):

Expanding the response from Chowlett to manage the posibility to "skip" elements.

Change the elements that you want to skin from div to nav (this would be pretty much the same).

Reference them by using nth-of-type selector instead of nth-child. and made the selector more specific to avoid changing the background of the navs

```
.menuItemWrapper div.menuItem:nth-of-type(4n+1), 
.menuItemWrapper div.menuItem:nth-of-type(4n+2) {
     background-color: #ccc; 
 }
```

### [modyfied demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3VQcP/3/)

(item 5 is skipped)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution to your problem based on Chowlett suggestion: http://jsfiddle.net/Z8Uxt/10/.

All it requires from you is to change the divider to different element type (eg: p instead of div or maybe even the semantic div instead of li).

The solution uses `:nth-of-type` as `:nth-child` count every child regardless of its class.