# css selector get 2 elements

Tags: html, css

I need to select two elements, skip the next two elements, select two elements, etc.

For example, assuming I have 10 elements:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="el">element1</div>
    <div class="el">element2</div>
    <div class="el">element3</div>
    <div class="el">element4</div>
    <div class="el">element5</div>
    <div class="el">element6</div>
    <div class="el">element7</div>
    <div class="el">element8</div>
    <div class="el">element9</div>
    <div class="el">element10</div>
</div>
```

I want select the elements 1, 2, 5, 6, 9, and 10.

Is there any way, utilizing `nth-child` or similar, to achieve this?

Comment: Possible answer here, duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16101674/using-nth-child-to-target-every-other-two-divs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`:nth-child()` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child) for this.

Combine selectors in order to select the first/second element for each four elements.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/wLn3mryv/)

```
.container > .el:nth-child(4n+1),
.container > .el:nth-child(4n+2) {
    color: red;
}
```

```css
.container > .el:nth-child(4n+1),
.container > .el:nth-child(4n+2) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="el">element1</div>
  <div class="el">element2</div>
  <div class="el">element3</div>
  <div class="el">element4</div>
  <div class="el">element5</div>
  <div class="el">element6</div>
  <div class="el">element7</div>
  <div class="el">element8</div>
  <div class="el">element9</div>
  <div class="el">element10</div>
</div>
```